# Good sound libraries?

Tags: python, ruby, linux, node.js, haskell

I need to take an audio signal, and extract overlapping audio frames from it. I then need to convert these to frequency data (FFT stuff / like a spectrogram) and analyze the frequency information.

For example, if I have a 1 minute mp3 file, I want split the file into smaller files, from 00:00.000 to 00:03.000, from 00:00.010 to 00:03.010. Then I need to see the frequency breakdown of each sub-file.

Which programming languages have good audio tools that could help  me do this? Are there linux command-line tools I could use? Bonus points for Node.js (yeah right) or Haskell, which I'm most familiar with.

Comment: In Python I've been successful with [Audiolab](http://www.ar.media.kyoto-u.ac.jp/members/david/softwares/audiolab/sphinx/index.html) with Numpy.

Comment: I would also use Python / Numpy.  If you want to deal with mp3 files, you need a library to decode them, such as ffmpeg.  You can call ffmpeg from python using subprocess calls.

Comment: There has been some discussion on audio libraries for node.js, but I don't know of anything mature. See [this discussion on the mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/5b62789562697956) for entry points. I'm thinking Python.

Comment: Not constructive - many (most?) languages have libraries that will help with various parts of your task.  You can find them by searching the web.

Comment: The moment you put "Good" in your question title I know it's a subjective question not appropriate for Stack Overflow. (That doesn't mean it's not a good question, or that the answers aren't helpful...but qualitative discussions and recommendations do not belong here.)

Comment: I've already searched the web for hours, of course. The problem is knowing good places to start. How would I ever have heard of SuperCollider?

Comment: You might like to look at hmatrix/hsignal and plot, available on Hackage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haskell:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hsndfile. Then it's mainly just math, I'd imagine, with hmatrix and soforth.

Comment: I'm actually playing around with python and scipy, but none of those guys put theirs in an answer :) TY! I might try out the haskell version, but the FFT functions made  my brain hurt

Comment: Note: libsndfile (the library being wrapped by hsndfile) does not work with mp3. http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/FAQ.html#Q020

Answer (score 3):

MATLAB.

GNU Octave is the free sorta-clone.

Comment: Wow matlab is expensive. Thanks for the alternative.

Comment: @SeanClarkHess: Expensive compared to what, dude?  How much would it cost you to write and debug all that code?  Also, if you're a full-time student, the student discount on Matlab used to be so good that you had to be a complete idiot not to grab it.  (In 2003, I did refresher work.  I hit the college computer store for the Microsoft bundle.  I saw the student Matlab edition.  It took me ZERO seconds to decide to say "Give me one of those, also."

Comment: Compared to free. I'm preparing an internal presentation on the subject for my startup. So, commercial license. I'll never use it for production code, just for the demo. I'm no more familiar with matlab than I am with regular old code, so it might not be that much faster for me. I need a "just playing around" license for Matlab :)

Comment: @SeanClarkHess: For a startup presentation, you should be able to get what you need with GNU Octave.  Data point: A MATLAB single-user commercial license is $2150.  Compare that to the price of a high-end PC, or a good oscilloscope.  For that matter, compare it to the price of an entry-level engineer, before and after overhead is taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [SuperCollider](http://supercollider.sourceforge.net/)? It's a full-featured language, and it has far more sound-processing features than most libraries for other languages.